# Are high power ceramic resistors waterproof?

Tags: resistors

I need to put some resistors on my jeep.  I picked up 2x 22ohm, 10watt resistors at a local electronic store.  They do the job well, but are they waterproof?  Can they hold up to the elements?

I put the resistors under the hood, so they should not get wet under normal usage - and I covered them in heat shrink. On the off chance that they get wet, will it chance their resistance?

I'm not talking about the striped cylindrical resistors, but the white rectangular ones.

Comment: Why not mount them under the dash instead of underhood?

Comment: That's a good idea... I didn't look at the wires under the hood, but I think that they control the relays, not the actual light.  The resistor needs to be in parallel with the light.  I will take a look though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On the off chance that they get wet, will it chance their resistance?

### Yes.

Unless they are sealed, yes. How much it changes depends on a few factors (impregnation depth, chemistry of the solution, volume, mass, and temperature).

They are made from a porous ceramic powder material so they will absorb moisture from the air and liquid in surface contact. However, if you run enough power through them, they will get hot and "bake" the moisture out. The bigger problem is the impurities left behind by the liquid.

### Seal them.

For reliability, seal them with an automative-grade silicon sealant and derate their power rating by 2.

What are you using them for exactly? (just curious)

Comment: Crap.  If I lower their power rating by 2x, then they cant handle the load at 12.8volts.  I have some aerospace grade silicone that I will use around the edge of the heatshrink - and hope that they hold up.  Maybe I should just order some nice surface mount resistors from digikey.  I am using them in parallel with LED turn signals.  Since the LEDs use so little power my jeep thought that they were burned out.

Comment: @DrFriedParts Here is an idea. Since these things are ceramic, I wonder whether it might not be possible to bake them a nice, shiny glaze?

Comment: Putting heat-shrink tubing on the resistors will reduce the power rating - you are insultating them from the surrounding air, so they cannot dissipate heat as well as the manufacturer intended.

Comment: Yeah, I figured.  After a 20 minute drive they were cool to the touch.  As of now, I am not too worried.  I think there is a decent amount of airflow in the engine bay which probably helps keep them cool.

Comment: The air in the engine bay is hot, sometimes very hot.  If the resistors are for turn signals only, the duty cycle is probably low enough that dissipation won't be an issue.  If they're used for stoplights also, then you may want to consider an alternate solution.

Comment: @HikeOnPast, they are used for running lights.  They are always on.  They are near the side of the engine bay, where air can - fairly easily - come in.  If the resistors fail, I will definitely let you know.  But I am optimistic.

Comment: Air doesn't flow so much when you are stuck in traffic for five minutes during a heatwave with a hot engine and a full tank of gas.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not water proof. Three things you could do. You could seal them, but since the good Dr. Fried Parts says the power ratings should be halved, you might need to double up on each resistor. Or you can mount them in a automotive rated case, like under the hood car fuse boxes are.

Or you could get Load Resistors designed for automotive use. They are encased in aluminum, to provide resistance against weather conditions without affecting thermal conductivity.

[image]

You could also just deal with them as is. Unless you are off roading in river, or driving through flood prone areas, cars normally do not get much if any water under the hood, especially at headlight level. If they did, alternators, batteries, lightbulbs, fuses would all have serious risk of damage with the current state car design.

How about an alternative solution(s)? 1, Get a second set of led turn signal bulbs, hook them up in parallel. You instantly get twice the load on the line.

2, disable or trick the current sense circuit on the line. If people can trick emissions systems to remove o2 sensors that way, I'm sure a simple light bulb burnout sensor or circuit/system can as well. You might need a factory wiring manual for that.

Answer (score 0):

Note also that the leads of this type of resistor are almost universally tinned copper wire, which is a combination that is not at all resistant to corrosion. They need to be kept clean and dry.

You also need to pay attention to how you connect wires (or whatever) to the resistor leads. A crimp connection will be more reliable than a soldered connection. But again, it needs to be kept clean and dry.

Comment: Hmm, well, I actually cut the resistor's leads down and then soldered it to a wire.  I then covered the connections with heat shrink.

Comment: What about a crimp and solder connection?